# Mongodb copy a collection into an other collection

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I need to copy a collection into an other collection to work with. What I have so far is

```
checkPoints.find().forEach(function(copy){'pdiCheckPoints'[MachineNr].insert(copy);});
```

But mongo throws the TypeError: Cannot call method 'insert' of undefined.

The copy works with

```
checkPoints.find().forEach(function(copy){pdiCheckPoints.insert(copy);});
```

but working with more than 1 Machine i need to add an id for each copy somehow.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What is a "machine" in your model? If `pdiCheckPoints` is a _collection_ then you can't index it like an _object_ with `[key]`

Comment: The machine should be the unique id with many checkpoints, so far the idea

Comment: That implies that `machine` is a separate collection or that it is just a key of your `pdiCheckPoints` collection. See possible solution.

Comment: Try a MongoDB GUI, this is a very simple gui action. Try http://mongobooster.com, the best gui I ever used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply *augment* your document with an additional key during the copy:

```
checkPoints.find().forEach(function(doc){
  doc.machineNumber = MachineNr;
  pdiCheckPoints.insert(doc);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this is help to u

```
db.oldCollection.aggregate([{$out : "newCollection"}])
```